# Understanding how ports work and how are they different from processes?

Tags: networking, operating-systems, process, port, tcp

I've been a part of a network operations team for quite some time now and was extracting a certificate using this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect <IP>:<PORT> </dev/null | sed -n -e '/-.BEGIN/,/-.END/ p'
```

I was not able to extract the certificates even though processes were running on ports. One thing led to another and now I am wondering the **difference** between a **port**, a **process**, and an **application**!

I understand that ports are a core part of the TCP/ IP framework and since Operating Systems (OS) work based on this, some sources mention ports as an OS concept. For now, let's just go with it so yes, operating systems use ports to distinguish traffic for applications.

So the question is even though no process/ application is using the port (or running on it), can I still connect to it? Or does the port have no meaning without a service or a process using it?

For example, take an HTTP request, while establishing a TCP connection, does the process matter, or is the process only responsible for responding to the HTTP request (actual payload)?

My understanding is that it might be that yes, ports have no meaning without processes and they are a package deal (hence, the various port states!).

Comment: One more thing, I believe that netstat only shows the ports with processes using them (hence the states!) but what about the ports with no processes? Can I still connect to them and how do I check these ports? Are these ports always open since it's an "OS concept"?

Comment: You can get some insight by reading how `nmap` port scanner classifies ports: https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html

Answer (score 1):

Very simplified: Consider a multi-party house with numbered apartments.

- The IP address is the street name + house number.
- The port is the number of the apartment.
- The application is what is happening inside the apartment.
- The application needs one or multiple processes to run, which are the inhabitants of the apartment doing things.

If you connect to an IP address and port you go into the house at this address and ring on the door to the apartment defined by the port.

If nobody opens then there might be nobody inside (no process, no application) or they might simply not currently expecting visitors (nobody listening).

If somebody opens then they might immediately close the door again since they don't like you, they might speak to you in a language you don't understand (wrong application protocol used) or you might actually be able to communicate as planned (matching application protocol).

It might be that you cannot simply go into the house and ring at the door, but that you first need to pass some [concierge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concierge) which might not like you. In this case they will reject you directly or simply claim that nobody is in the apartment, even if there is one. That's the firewall.

Comment: Thanks for the analogy, it helped but it also led to some follow-ups like the one I mentioned under the answer by @Spiff

Answer (score 0):

A port will not be open (listening, waiting to receive connections/flows) unless a process has told the stack it wants to listen on that port. In the terminology of the popular cross-platform "BSD Sockets" API for TCP/IP programming, this is called "opening a listener socket". The BSD Sockets API concept of a socket is a programming abstraction that maps closely onto to the concept of a port in TCP or UDP.

Most OSes also have some form of "internet daemon" or "lazy launch daemon" that is guaranteed to be running at all times, and is configured to open listeners on ports on behalf of other software binaries. When it gets a connection attempt on such a port, it launches the binary that had been configured to use that port, and then hands off the connection to that newly-launched process. That way you don't need a ton of different server process all running all the time, taking up CPU and RAM, just idling waiting for rare connection attempts. Lazy launch daemons include inetd, xinetd, launchd, and more.

There are well-known ports that are common default ports for certain protocols, such as port 80 being used for HTTP and port 22 for SSH, but that's not a hard rule. You could tell sshd to listen on port 80 and have httpd listen on port 22, and it would work just fine as long as you specify those other ports when telling your client apps to connect.

Note that this means that when establishing a TCP connection, neither end can know for sure what protocol the process at the other end is about to try to use. There is no standard for server apps to recognize each others' protocols and hand off errant connection attempts, so if your web browser connects to a port where sshd, not httpd, is listening, the behavior will be unpredictable. One end or the other will probably give up trying to deal with the unexpected behavior of the other end, and reset (abort) the connection.

If a TCP SYN (connection attempt) comes in for a port that no process has opened a listener on, the OS's TCP stack will respond with a TCP Reset and perhaps also an ICMP "Destination unreachable: port unreachable" error message packet. Of course as with any network traffic, you might have a firewall or other policy-enforcement software in place on your systems that blocks these responses from reaching the host that attempted the connection, so the originating host might not hear anything back at all and would presumably time out and give up the attempt after a while.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer, a quick follow-up: what you are essentially saying is that ports will be "hibernating" unless called upon by a process and we cannot connect to them, and yes, the ports are an OS thing, and depending upon the process using a port, the OS will be responding accordingly (a TCP reset by your example). Can I also generalize that the networking behavior at least up to Layer 4 is done by the OS?

Comment: "Hibernating" isn't the way I'd describe it. A port is just a number in a packet header. The OS's network stack keeps a lookup table of which processes have registered to listen to which port numbers. If a packet comes in with a destination port number that's not in the table, the OS declines the connection attempt, because no one is interested in that connection attempt. If the port number had been in the table, the OS would use the table entry to know which process to hand off the connection to. And yes, in general the OS handles most of the protocol stack below the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is even though no process/ application is using the port (or running on it), can I still connect to it? Or does the port have no meaning without a service or a process using it?

In general – no, you cannot.

Think of a port number as an extension to the address. The IP address leads you to a specific host; the port number further leads you to a specific process (or rather, a specific *socket<sup>1</sup>*) within that host. If the OS receives a packet without there being a socket (in appropriate state) that is bound to the address & port, normally it'll reject the packet.

The kernel itself may handle packets for certain ports (e.g. on Linux, TCP port 2049 would be handled by the in-kernel NFS server); this is usually still represented as a socket, without a corresponding process.

<sup>1</sup> Processes don't directly work with ports; they work with sockets, which are bound to a certain address:port but otherwise operate like file handles or file descriptors. Much like an open file, a socket may be created by one process and inherited by its child processes.